# Ember.js - make action target controller automatically

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

In Ember, if I use the Router, any `{{action}}` helpers automatically target the view's controller, when the view was created by the router.

How can I make views' `{{actions}}` target the controller when the Router doesn't create the view. I thought setting the `controller` property would do it, but it doesn't appear to.

Comment: I think I have the solution, with {{action target="controller"}}, but if you give a jsfiddle, perhaps I could confirm that

Comment: I'm asking how I can avoid needing to specify the target in the action. Is there a way I could word it better?

Answer (score 4):

You would need to set a `controller` property on the view pointing to your controller, and define a `target` property on the controller like so:

```
App.MyController = Em.Controller.extend({
    target: function(){
        return this;
    }.property()
    ...
});
```

Comment: +1, I think my way of defining the target property does not work.